# Error when Uploading csv file in Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, api, rest

I have the below powershell script which is returning the value as success but it is not getting uploaded to the target system.

```
$Uri ="https://example.com"
$Auth_Token = 'xxxx'
$headers = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $($Auth_Token)"}
$file ='C:\Users\r\feedfile.csv'
$fields =@{}
$fields.add("file",$file)
$FieldJson = $fields | ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Headers $headers -ContentType "multipart/form-data;boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p" -Body $FieldJson
```

Comment: Enter the error message, or it will be hard to answer your problem

Comment: Error message would be great. But try "-Compress" with "ConvertTo-Json".

Answer (score 0):

To me without an error message, my guess is that your not creating a json output from your csv file, as your not importing the csv file and also you content type is not correct. it should be '**-ContentType = "application/json"**' and not '"multipart/form-data;boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p"'

**Steps To Test CSV to Json Conversion**

1. Generate File Path
2. Import CSV File
3. Create PowerShell Array
4. Add CSV data to PowerShell Array
5. Convert PowerShell Array To Json

**Example Script To Test CSV to Json Conversion**
I've hashed out the parts used for your invoke-restmethod. To test the create json from csv file (see picture for validation of the below & amend accordingly to test yourself).

```
#$Uri ="https://example.com"
#$Auth_Token = 'xxxx'
#$headers = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $($Auth_Token)"}

#Generate File Path
$folderspath = 'C:\Test'
$csvfilename = 'info.csv'
$csvfilepath = $folderspath + "\" + $csvfilename
$csvfilepath = $csvfilepath.ToString()

$jsonFilename = 'info.json'
$jsonfilepath = $folderspath + "\" + $jsonFilename
$jsonfilepath = $jsonfilepath.ToString()

#Create A Json File From CSV File
#import-csv $csvfilepath | ConvertTo-Json | Add-Content -Path $jsonfilepath

#Import CSV
$csvfile = Import-CSV -Path $csvfilepath

#PowerShell Array
$fields =@{}

#Get csv file
Write-Host "Import Full CSV File For Json Test"
$fields = $csvfile

#Get Column Headers for test
#Write-Host "Import CSV File Headers For Json Test"
#$fields = ($csvfile[0].psobject.Properties).name
#$fields

#Convert To Json
$FieldJson = $fields | ConvertTo-Json
$FieldJson


#Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Headers $headers -ContentType "multipart/form-data;boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p" -Body $FieldJson

#Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json" -Body $FieldJson
```

[image: Json Output Test]